# Scripting Tortoise SVN

Tags: svn, scripting, batch-file, tortoisesvn

Is it possible to script tortoise svn from a batch file or a visual studio project?  I want to be able to create a batch file that will automatically get the latest version of a file and acquire a lock for that file.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you just write a script that uses command-line SVN directly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apart from what @BishopRook said, if you are creating a .Net app ( from what you mentioned as a visual studio project) you can use an SVN client API like SharpSVN - http://sharpsvn.open.collab.net/

It will be very easy to program using the API and get what you want.

I cannot see how you can do a complete scripting using TortosieProc.exe as @jason.rickman mentions.

Even the page for "automating" TortoiseSVN gives the below warning:

> Remember that TortoiseSVN is a GUI client, and this automation guide
>   shows you how to make the TortoiseSVN dialogs appear to collect user
>   input. If you want to write a script which requires no input, you
>   should use the official Subversion command line client instead.

For example, for the locking that the OP wants:

> :lock  Locks a file or all files in a directory given in /path. The
>   **'lock' dialog** is shown so the user can enter a comment for the lock.

It shows a dialog. There is no way to directly lock it. You have to proceed from the dialog. It will be very cumbersome / impossible to script with this. That is why the command line client or library / API for various platforms is the ideal solution.

Answer (score 2):

It would be much easier to just script a command-line SVN client.  I'm a fan of [SlikSVN](http://www.sliksvn.com/en/download) because it's easy to install and gets out of your way.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. The TortoiseSVN documentation describes how to use TortoiseProc.exe to execute Subversion commands through TortoiseSVN: http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-automation.html